# Can "household" be treated as a person?

Tags: meaning

According to [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/household) **household** means:

> a house and its occupants regarded as a unit, e.g., ‘the whole
>   household was asleep’.

The question in my mind is if it can be regarded as the agent of an action. For example, is the following sentence correct or not?

*This chart demonstrates the distribution of renting and owning accommodation by households in percentage during 1918 to 2011 in England and Wales.*

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A corporation can rent or own property, _as an entity_. But a household is not an entity. The _householder_ is the entity who rents or possesses.

Comment: @NigelJ The OP's sentence in italics sounds fine as metonymy.

Comment: @NigelJ In the UK, a property can be *jointly* rented / owned by two or more people.  If those people are the sole occupants, then effectively the householders and the occupants are identical.

Comment: I would treat *household* in exactly the same way as *audience*. (Specific context aside.)